# How to capture a drop-down menu?

Tags: menu, screenshot

I need to capture a drop-down menu of a program. If I open the menu and then press <kbd>PrntScr</kbd> (print screen button), it first closes the menu and then captures the screen. I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PrntScr</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrntScr</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrntScr</kbd> but no success. I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 42):

Run the Screenshot program (`gnome-screenshot`, or search for *Screenshot* in the Dash). Set a timeout (or delay):

[image: gnome-screenshot]

And then get the menu and wait for the timeout to expire.

This only works with a whole-screen screenshot. So you'll have to manually crop later:

[image: captured drop-down menu]

Comment: Running `gnome-screenshot` just takes a screenshot. Is there any way to launch that graphical interface from the terminal? (Just mildly curious.)

Comment: @TRiG `gnome-screenshot -i`, though you can set the delay directly (`-d 5`).

Comment: Thanks. And `--help` shows that, of course. If I had more sense, I'd've found it myself.

Comment: This doesn't work in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04 the GUI seems to have been removed as well (or still), but as mentioned above, not a problem: Just run "gnome-screenshot -help" to see all options. Also as mentioned above "gnome-screenshot --delay=SECONDS" (or just -d) does the job.

Comment: @Prof.Chaos I don't use Ubuntu for a desktop anymore, but on Arch, which should have a newer version of gnome-screenshot (40, where 20.04 uses 3.36), the GUI's still there: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XcCr.png

Comment: @Prof.Chaos In 20.04 the GUI is still there. You can access it either via searching for "screenshot" in the dash or by running `gnome-screenshot -i` as suggested in [muru's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/584778/how-to-capture-a-drop-down-menu#comment912522_584779).

Answer (score 5):

This is really simple using shutter and the best thing about using shutter is that you don't get to crop your menu later. It just captures the menu specified.

1. Install and launch shutter

   ```
   sudo apt-get install shutter
   ```
2. Using the shutter window, click on the 'menu' icon. See screenshot below:

   [image]
3. You will then be prompted to choose and click on which menu you want captured. Let's take for example Firefox - my browser. See screenshot below:

   [image]

Comment: Indeed, shutter should be the default.

Comment: I disagree.  I just tried this and the real problem is that it grabs *only* the menu.  I frequently need context.  I think the first answer is better, but there should be an easier way to do a timeout on a selection of the screen.

Comment: how hard is it to caputure a menu in a screen shot, wow

Comment: For me, shutter on Ubuntu Unity grabs the wrong rectangles.

Answer (score 3):

Install the `imagemagick` package, then issue the following command on a terminal:

```
$ sleep 10; import -window root /tmp/screenshot.png
```

In the next 10 seconds change your active window, open the dropdown menu and wait. You will likely need to crop your screenshot afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Flameshot](https://flameshot.org/), it also has an option to capture a rectangular area so you won't have to manually crop it.

Create a shortcut to these commands for easy access:

```
flameshot launcher
```

and

```
flameshot gui
```

[image]

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me (Ubuntu 20.04, Flameshot 0.6.0).

I do not see a Delay option in the GUI, but I can use `flameshot gui -d 5000` from the command line to get a 5s delay.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open screencapture program using the "ubuntu button" then type "screen"
2. There is a number field called "with a delay" add aproximately 4 seconds
3. click on take screencapture
4. open drop down menu
5. wait until your screenshot is made

Answer (score 0):

I like flameshot too, but another useful program is `peek`, it lets you capture animated gifs.

Install with the command:
`sudo apt install peek`

Place the Window over the area you want to capture, press record and do the normal actions you want to show. Pressing stop recording will show a prompt where to save the file. The output file size is minimal.